# Download files from webservice

Tags: php, android, web-services, download

I want to download files from my server.
I noticed the right way is to use webserver.

Should I give the download link in my webservice for each file?

Should I make many fields like :link, icon, screenshots, discriptions,... and request the proper data by android app?

How can I update webservice data (for example user adds a star to the rank of that specific file)

How can I track the number of downloads for that specific file?
How Can I add a search functionality between my files (request from android app). 
This app is kind of app-store or download center for downloading files.

I know these are many questions. But I just want a hint.